Jest: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getItem') when trying to mock Async Storage
I am struggling getting my jest spec to work with AsyncStorage. I followed the guide on Jest integration with Async Storage and used the guidance for setting up the mocks directory. This makes my project structure look like so...
 .
My async-storage.js has the following contents...
export * from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock";

The spec I am trying to test is checking that I redirect the user to a certain page based on the values retrieved from storage. This is how the spec is set up (please excuse that it is the nicest looking right now - just trying to get the tests to work for now!)...
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";

import Index from "@/src/app/index";

jest.mock("expo-router", () => ({
  useNavigation: jest.fn(),
  useFocusEffect: jest.fn().mockImplementation((callback) => callback()),
  useRouter: jest.fn()
}));

describe("Index page", () => {
  const mockRouter = {
    replace: jest.fn()
  }
  ;(useRouter as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(mockRouter)

  async function asyncOperationOnAsyncStorage(firstTime: string){
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("firstTime", firstTime)

    await AsyncStorage.getItem("firstTime")
  }

  it("renders successfully", async () => {
    render(<Index />);
  });

  it("redirects to 'First Launch' page when the user opens the app for the first time", async () => {
    await asyncOperationOnAsyncStorage("");
    render(<Index />);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockRouter.replace).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/first-launch");
    })
  })

  it("redirects to 'Login' page when it is not the user's first time using the app", async () => {
    await asyncOperationOnAsyncStorage("DONE");

    render(<Index />);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockRouter.replace).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/login");
    })
  })

The index page is coded up like so...
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useFocusEffect, useRouter } from "expo-router";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

export default function Index() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleRedirect = async () => {
    try {
      const firstTime = await AsyncStorage.getItem("firstTime");
      
      if (firstTime !== "DONE") {
        router.replace("/first-launch");
      else {
        router.replace("/login");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Cannot retrieve data from storage", error);
      router.replace("/first-launch");
    }
  }

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      handleRedirect()
    }, [handleRedirect])
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Redirecting...</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


I thought I had my async set up right, but whenever I run the tests, I get this error in the console...
Cannot retrieve data from storage TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getItem')

This implies that the spec fails when performing async's getItem when running my index's handleRedirect() function. This error does not occur when I run the app, so I assume I must not have set up my Jest and Async Storage integration right - but I have no clue where I went wrong!
Thank you in advance for any help!

The problem seems to be resolved now. The fix was to change my async-storage.js to...
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock";
export default AsyncStorage;

...And then change my import for AsyncStorage on my index spec file to be import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock";
